# Is it possible to customize the years range in bootstrap date picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a attribute name is assessment year,in that attribute if i choose the year(ex 2012),the bootstrap date picker display the 2012 calendar only

**my js file**

```js
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
     format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
     todayHighlight: true,
     todayBtn: 'linked',
     autoclose: true
  });
```

I searched the lot of things,still i am not get a correct answer...help me friends

Comment: you mean the datepicker display dates from 2012 only?

Comment: yes @NewbeeDev that's right

Comment: maybe adding minDate: "2016-01-01", endDate: "2016-12-31" will solve it

Comment: @NewbeeDev minDate is not working but the startDate will resolve the problem

Comment: so you now solve it?

Comment: @NewbeeDev is it possible to show that year dynamically? means if i choose any year, it shows that year's calendar by passing any id to datapicker.js

Comment: yes off course it is

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124204/discussion-between-praveenkumar-and-newbee-dev).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple just add startDate and endDate assuming that you selected year "2016" http://jsfiddle.net/LcqM7/542/

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    startDate: '01/01/2016',
    endDate: '12/31/2016'
});
```